# Получить все значения Input и записать в масив

Tags: jquery

Есть разметка

```
<form class="inputs">
<input type="text" value="1"/>
<input type="text" value="2"/>
<input type="text" value="3/>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку нужно получить все значения input и записать в массив.

Делаю так но не работает.

```
 $('.test').click(function() {
     var test = [];

       $('.inputs').find(':input').each(function(i, input) {

       test.push(input.value());
       });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот Вам работающий пример...

```js
$('#go').click(function() {
  var test = [];

  $('.inputs').find(':input').each(function(i, input) {
    test.push($(input).val());
  });

  alert(test);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="inputs">
  <input type="text" value="1" />
  <input type="text" value="2" />
  <input type="text" value="3" />
</form>

<button id="go">пуск</button>
```